# Filter Data from Data Table in C#

Tags: c#

I have a data table which is having columns as follows,

```
Column01 - ID ,
Column02 - Emp_Number ,
Column03 - Date ,
Column04 - Time_In/Out ,
```

`Column04` is intended to used to store time in & time out of the employees.Since this table holds the finger print punching time there will be several records per particular date per particular person.

So I want to create data table using the above data table which is having only one data row for a person for particular day.Which means I have to merge columns with filtering.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to group by Id,Emp_Number and Date

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dataview to filter data

```
DataView DV= new DataView(YourDataTable);
DataTable filterdDT= DV.ToTable(true, "ID", "Emp_Number","Date ");
```

Comment: I think I should where clause to filter the data..but I dont knoow the syntax for to do that..

Comment: the function toTABLE with the Parameter true will give you distinct values